# yii 1.1 cgridview with form input fields and new row

Tags: php, forms, yii, cgridview

I want to create a cgridview where i can use editable form data and able to insert a new row. how can i achieve this. I have the following so far.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                            'id'=>'jobs-grid',
                            'dataProvider'=>$job->searchbyproject($model->PROJID),
                            //'filter'=>$job,
                            'summaryText' => '',
                            'columns'=>array(   
                                array(
                                    'name'=>'NAME',
                                    'value'=>'CHtml::activeTextField($data, "[$row]NAME")' ,
                                    'type'=>'raw',
                                ),
                                'SEQ',
                                'DATEIN',
                                array(
                                    'header'=>'Process Complete <br>' . $processcompleteheader,
                                    'value'=>''
                                ),
                                'DATEDONE',
                                'COMMENTS',                         
                                array(
                                    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                                    'template'=>'{update}{delete}',
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the same technique below.

```
<?php 
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'accounts-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'columns'=>array(
                array(
                        'name'=>'commodityId',
                        'value'=>function($data){
                            return '<input type="Text" value="'.$data-  >commodityId.'" />';
                        }
                        ,
                        'type'=>'raw'
                    ),
    ));
?>
```